# what makes this program code to print 4

Tags: c, memory, pointers, undefined

```
int main(){
  int *p=0;
  printf("%d",++p);
}
```

In my machine, I am getting output as 4; I initially thought *p points to address 0 and incrementing of it points to address 4 from 0.

latter I declared *p = -1; which I thought should throw error because -1 can't be an address but it prints "3" :(

Please let me know what is happening here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please search "pointer" in C++

Comment: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." Since your pointer doesn't point to any object, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Also passing the wrong argument type to printf results in UB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int *p=0` declares a pointer at address 0.

`++p` increments that pointer by the host-specific `sizeof int`.  This is 4 bytes on your system.

`int *p=-1` gives you a pointer with address `0xffffffff` (assuming 32-bit pointers)

`++p` is equivalent to `0xffffffff + 4` which is `0x100000003`.  This overflows a 32-bit int, leaving you with `0x00000003`.

Comment: `++p` is well-defined; it increments the pointer by the size of the object pointed to, i.e. `sizeof(int)`.  `int *p = 0` is a null pointer, so not necessarily at address 0 (though it is on most modern systems).

Comment: @ecatmur Thanks, I've updated my answer to be clearer about the behaviour of ++p

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behavior.

When you say:

```
int* p = 0;
```

You're declaring a pointer to null (or `nullptr` in C++11). Then when you do:

```
printf("%d", ++p);
```

You're printing the location of the pointer, but you're passing an incorrect format string, this is undefined.

It happens to work, because on your architecture, an int is the same size as a pointer. It says `4` because adding `1` to your pointer moves the address by the size of an integer, in your case 4 bytes.

Comment: @sidyll The incorrect format string is though.

Comment: @sidyll Since the pointer doesn't point to an object, the `++p` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I didn't really know about this definition. Anyway, the act of incrementing an int pointer doesn't seem to be undefined to me, since it will result in an address sizeof(int) bigger, whatever it points to (valid or not). I'm not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: That what the pointer is pointg to is irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @sidyll The standard says that if the pointer and the result of the addition point into the same array or one past the end [an object not part of an array is treated as a one-element array here], the result is defined, **otherwise the behaviour is undefined**. You'd have a very hard time finding an implementation that does something else here, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot for the clarification, I didn't know these details!

Comment: @Collin Thanks for correcting the memory access part and including such valuable information in the answer, +1

Comment: I believe printing a pointer with %d rather than %p is also undefined behavior nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

We can check C standard for ruling whether C implementation should allow negative pointer or not. However, -1 might be valid address value(0xffffffff in 32bit), and incrementing it results in 0xffffffff + 4 = 0x03.